# Bold an active link in meteor

Tags: css, meteor, hyperlink, iron-router

I have this code in my navigation bar in Meteor and I'm trying to bold the link when it's active. I've tried using CSS and `a:active {}` but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="navSecondary">
    <div class="menu" align="center">
        <ul class="menu-items">

            <li class="active">
            <a href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"> HOME </a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS in Meteor works just like usual. But what do you mean by "active"? Active as in "a link that is active" or active as in "The `<li>` element with the class `active`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bold the navigation link on a current page first install the zimme:iron-router-active. This should create a class called "active" when an item is clicked.

Then in your html navigation html for example, type in {{ isActiveRoute 'home'}}. This means that when home is clicked, it will change the class from whatever it was before to a class called "active"

```
<li class="{{ isActiveRoute 'home'}}">
            <a class="home" href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"> HOME </a></li>
```

Finally in your CSS type:

```
   .active a {
        color: black;
    }

    .menu .active a {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

This should produce a result of bolding the current navigation bar.

Answer (score 7):

With iron:router I created this "active" template helper to add the active class to the menu item associated with the current page/route:

```
Template.registerHelper("active", function(routeName) {
  var curRoute = Router.current().route;
  return curRoute.getName() === routeName ? 'active' : '';
};
```

In template:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="{{active 'page1'}}">
    <a href="{{pathFor 'page1'}}">Page1</a></li>

  <li class="{{active 'page2'}}">
    <a href="{{pathFor 'page2'}}">Page2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will this bold the link as long as you stay on the page? (i.e. if you switch to a Page 2, Page 1 becomes unbolded and Page 2 becomes bold instead)

Comment: yes, it makes the menu item active according to the current page (iron route name)

Comment: +1 this is the best way to do it. If you do it with click events, the link wont be active if a user directly navigates to a page (by, say, typing in the link address). By using the router you will ensure that this always works.

Comment: How would the CSS look like to make it bold? So far this is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working. 

.menu a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu a:active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

This seems to only highlight it as I hover over it but not while active.

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis in the global helper code

Answer (score 1):

Just add this.

```
Template.home.events({
'mouseenter a':function(){ //"a" can be replaced for an id or classname
    var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    link.style.color = "BLACK";
    //or whatever you want to do
    console.log("passed")
  }
})
```

Like @Peppe L-G say Meteor works exactly like other frameworks with CSS.

Just put this on the .css file.

```
a:hover { 
    background-color: black; //for example
    font-weight:bold; //this will change to bold the text
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't bolding the HOME link when it's clicked. Is there something I'm missing? Is there some way I can do this in CSS?

Comment: How would I keep it bolded as long as I stay on the home page?

Comment: if you want to keep them in bold when the router its open, why don't just put as a bold always? with simple .css

Comment: this is just a hover over - the OP wants the link to be active or bold depending on which page the user is on.

Comment: Ramsay is right. I don't want it to be bold all the time. Just when the link is active do I want it to be bold.

Comment: @RamsayLanier "and I'm trying to bold the link when it's active" its open to have many answers don't you think?

Comment: @Ethaan I think it is a pretty standard pattern to have the "active" link be bold (or differentiated somehow), and the definition of the "active" link to be the link of the page you are currently on.